# Prefix not found: 'tib' in Tibco designer

Tags: tibco

I got the following error in Tibco.

> com.tibco.xml.data.primitive.PrefixToNamespaceResolver$PrefixNotFoundException: Prefix not found: 'tib'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before using any `tib:` prefixed XSLT function you have to define the prefix. Select the process, click the `namespace registry` button and add
the namespace `http://www.tibco.com/bw/xslt/custom-functions` with prefix `tib`.